# Multiple unit tests on the same data accessible in a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mocha.js, chai

I implemented a parser to extract data from an Excel file and return an object with a certain structure. To make the code work asynchronously, I used a simple **callback** scheme for the further processing of the extracted data:

```
parse(inputFile, callback) {
    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook.xlsx.readFile(inputFile).then((workbook) => {
        // Parsing
        callback(result);
    });
}
```

Now I want to write a **unit test** for this routine using `Mocha` and `Chai`. Of course I can simply put the `expect()`statements in the callback function:

```
const ExcelParser = require('ExcelParser');
var chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('Unit::Test parsing', () => {
  const excelParser = new ExcelParser();

  it('should parse the data correctly', (done) => {
    excelParser.parse('sheet.xlsx', (data) => {
      expect(data).to.have.property('mainContent');
      expect(data['mainContent']).to.be.an('array');
    });

    done();
  });

});
```

This works fine, but I want to write more tests for the returned data object in separate `it()` blocks. By doing it this way, the **parsing would be repeated for every single subtest**.

I tried putting the call of `parse()` in a `before()` block and define a callback method that stores the result object in a global variable, but obviously the parsing is not finished by the time the tests are run.

What is the best way to do this, if it is possible at all? Would it help if the `parse()` method returned a `Promise` rather than working with callbacks?

Comment: In `.then()` set a global var to the result you use in the callback, and then just put a check for that global var at the beginning of the parse function.  Just execute the callback immediately, without making the call, and return.  If you can wrap this up in some type of test scope then it would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by parsing in the `before` block passing `done`. Then test in the `it` statements as normal,

```
const ExcelParser = require('ExcelParser');
var chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('Unit::Test parsing', () => {
  const excelParser = new ExcelParser();
  let data = null;

  before((done) => {
    excelParser.parse('sheet.xlsx', (result) => {
      data = result;
      done();
    });
  })

  it('should parse the data correctly', () => {
     expect(data).to.have.property('mainContent');
     expect(data['mainContent']).to.be.an('array');
  });

  it('should have prop foo', () => {
     expect(data).to.have.property('foo');
  });

  ...

});
```

Assuming `excelParser.parse` returned a promise, you wouldn't need passing `done` to `before`:

```
 before(() => {
    return excelParser.parse('sheet.xlsx')
      .then((result) => {
        data = result;
      });
  })
```

Comment: This was actually simpler than expected. Thank you very much!